# Como ejecutar una transaccion dentro de un Comando

Tags: c#, sql, transacciones

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion que va a registrar un pedido y para ello necesito usar las sentencias de transaccion. He desarrollado un intento que a continuacion les adjuntare y sale el siguiente error:

> Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException' en
>   System.Data.dll
>
> Información adicional: ExecuteNonQuery requiere que el comando tenga
>   una transacción cuando la conexión asignada al mismo está en una
>   transacción local pendiente. No se ha inicializado la propiedad
>   Transaction del comando.

La verdad no tengo ni idea de como resolverlo, porque soy nuevo en esto de transacciones. Si alguno puede ayudarme estaria muy agradecido

CODIGO : Clase Transaccion

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Text; using System.Threading.Tasks; using System.Data; using System.Data.SqlClient; using System.Data; using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CapaDatos { public class Transaccion { DataManager dataManager = new DataManager(); SqlDataReader leer; SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(); DataTable tabla = new DataTable();

    public void RegistrarPedido(string descripcion, int idCliente, string 
    idRepartidor, double montoTotal)
    {
        comando.Connection = dataManager.AbrirConexion();
        dataManager.BeginTransaction();
        comando.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PEDIDOSCLIENTES VALUES ('" +  
        descripcion + "','" + idCliente + "','" + idRepartidor + "','" + 
        montoTotal + "')";
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dataManager.Commit();
    } }
```

CODIGO: Clase DataManager

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Text; using System.Threading.Tasks; using System.Data; using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CapaDatos { public class DataManager { SqlConnection Conexion = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TOSHIBA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=baseDeDatosPedidos;Integrated Security=True"); SqlTransaction Transaccion;

    public SqlConnection AbrirConexion()
    {
        if (Conexion.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            Conexion.Open();
        return Conexion;
    }
    public SqlConnection CerrarConexion()
    {
        if (Conexion.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            Conexion.Close();
        return Conexion;
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        if (Transaccion != null)
            Transaccion.Commit();
    }

    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        if (Conexion.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            Transaccion = Conexion.BeginTransaction();
    }
    public void Rollback()
    {
        if (Transaccion != null)
            Transaccion.Rollback();
    }
} }
```

Comment: Debes controlar el caso de que falle algo, en ese caso se hace Rollback, el concepto es simple, haces todo o no haces nada.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 5):

Las transacciones son una forma de encapsular acciones sobre la base de datos que deben ejecutarse todas juntas. El caso mas común, es el de las cuentas bancarias. Cuando sacamos plata de una cuenta para meterla en otra, queremos que las dos cosas ocurran o ninguna.

En ese caso, los querys se ponen dentro de una transacción, para que la base de datos trate de hacer todas y solo grabe todas las acciones cuando esta segura de poder realizar todas.

Para ello, la DB bloquea tablas y registros, para que no pueda ocurrir que los datos cambien en el medio.

El error que estas recibiendo, dice que tu query no esta asociado a ninguna transacción. Tene en cuenta que en una DB puede haber montones de transacciones ocurriendo al mismo tiempo.

Te falta, antes de ejecutar tu command, pasarle la propiedad `SqlCommand.Transaction`, que en tu caso seria:

```
comando.Transaction = DataManager.transaction
```

Tene en cuenta que la clase DataManager necesita devolver eso de alguna forma (en tu clase, no hay forma de obtenerlo).

Aparte de eso, como bien te dice @shop350 en los comentarios, toda la idea de la transacción, es que puedas volver atras si hay un error, cosa que no estas haciendo.

Deberias controlar si la ejecución del query no fue satisfactoria, de alguna forma, y si pasa eso, hacer un Rollback.